# Perl, Why is @INC different?

Tags: perl, library-path

I have a simple Perl script that prints out `@INC` as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $_, "\n" for @INC;
```

I execute the script in 2 different ways with `./test.pl` and `perl test.pl`, the output as the following:

```
[neevek@~/bin]$ ./test.pl 
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.12
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3
/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.12
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12
.   
[neevek@~/bin]$ perl test.pl 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3
/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
.
```

My question is: what's behind the scenes for executing a perl script with `./script.pl` and `perl script.pl`? what causes the script to output different `@INC`?

Comment: Different `perl` binaries?   What does `which perl` say?

Comment: `which perl` says `/opt/local/bin/perl`, but I used `/usr/bin/perl` for the shabang. you all are correct, thank you...but I could I have missed that...

Comment: Unix lesson #1 (that I give to all newbies in the team). NEVER EVER EVER rely on current directory or PATH. ALWAYS use explicit fully qualified path.

Comment: I’d say that relying on environment makes sense at least in some cases, for example it makes it easy to switch Perls with [Perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The script is executing `perl` from `/usr/bin` through the shebang line, but launching the script from the command line uses a different `perl` binary, from `/opt/somewhere` (see `which perl` for the path). You can use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` to make both options behave the same.

Answer (score 10):

You have two perl installations on your system.

When you execute `./test.pl`, it's `/usr/bin/perl` that is chosen, as written on the first line of your script.

When you execute `perl test.pl`, it's the first perl found in the `PATH` environment variable that is chosen. Type `which perl` to discover where it is.